# How do I get a shell script to properly shuffle array values?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a fantastic shell script that works beautifully: takes a string of Unicode values and shuffles them.  Problem is that I need to make absolutely sure that each value is in a different location in the string.

For example, if my string is (just using ascii):

abcdefg

I need to know that none of those chars will be in the same spot after the shuffle:

gbadcef won't work because the "d" is in the same spot.  Taking the very last value and putting it first would work...

fabcde

...but it doesn't give me the randomness I need for the application.

The actual data string is Unicode values, long, long, long semi-colon delimited strings:

```
&#x020AE;&#x0201E;&#x0202E;&#x02033;&#x020DD;&#x010AE;&#x200AE;&#x0009E; etc.
```

Here's the shuffle code I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input Filename:";
read ifilename;
echo "Output Filename:";
read ofilename;
cat $ifilename | sed -r 's/(.[^;]*;)/ \1 /g' | tr " " "\n" | shuf | tr -d "\n" > $ofilename;
```

It's a great, tight, wonderful script that I think came from someone out here in the StackOverflow community.  Can anyone tell me how to modify it so that it will ensure that no character anywhere in the string accidentally ends up in the same place?

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: What kind of randomness do you need?  Your restraint makes the output less random, not more.

Comment: As long as it's "well shuffled" it doesn't have to be as random as it possibly can be.  The randomness is less important than knowing that each char is in a different location after the "deck" is shuffled.

Comment: Your existing script could easily be modified to your new requirements. Instead of adding a space between all characters and replacing that with a newline, replace each ampersand with a newline. After shuffling, remove the empty line and add an ampersand to the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is not useful because I didn't see the `perl` tag but I would use that tool for the job. The script takes two arguments, an input file to read unicode strings and an output file to write shuffled strings.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

## Check arguments for two files, one for input and other for output.
die qq[Usage: perl $0 <input-file> <output-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 2;

## Open files.
open my $ifh, qq[<], shift @ARGV or die qq[Cannot open argument file\n];
open my $ofh, qq[>], shift @ARGV or die qq[Cannot open argument file\n];


## Read from input file ...
while ( <$ifh> ) { 

    ## Array with suffled characters.
    my @shuffle;

    ## Remove last newline character.
    chomp;

    ## Create an array with chars of input string.
    my @f = split /;/;

    ## Repeat: Shuffle array until no char keeps
    ## its original position.
    SHUFFLE: while ( 1 ) { 
        @shuffle = shuffle @f; 
        for my $i ( 0 .. $#f ) { 
            next SHUFFLE if $shuffle[ $i ] eq $f[ $i ];
        }   
        last;
    }   

    ## Print shuffled array.
    printf $ofh qq[%s\n], join qq[;], @shuffle;
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
&#x020AE;&#x0201E;&#x0202E;&#x02033;&#x020DD;&#x010AE;&#x200AE;&#x0009E;
&#x02043;&#x02099;&#x0ABCD;&#x02033;&#x020DD;
```

Run the script with correct arguments:

```
perl script.pl infile outfile
```

And content of `outfile` after execution:

```
&#x020DD;&#x010AE;&#x02033;&#x0009E;&#x0201E;&#x020AE;&#x0202E;&#x200AE
&#x02099;&#x0ABCD;&#x02033;&#x020DD;&#x02043
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not very familiar with perl but it doesn't have to be bash.  For the above, can it be done with similar queries for the input file (a .txt file that would become the DATA section above) and write to an output file that's specified by the user?  I'm also not sure why I run the script with the "for" loop -- I will need to do this only twice per file (but I have hundreds of files).

Comment: @user1149499: Modified the script to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The following Bash script shuffles a list of characters randomly, while preventing characters from occupying their previous position.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=";"
while read -r -a array
do
    num=${#array[@]}
    for ((i = 0; i < num; i++))
    do
        r=$i
        while ((r == i)) || [[ ${new[r]} ]]
        do
            ((r = $RANDOM % num))
        done
        new[r]=${array[i]}
    done
    echo "Input:  ${array[*]}"
    echo "Output: ${new[*]}"
done
```

Example:

```
$ charshuf < charfile
Input:  a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l
Output: j;h;i;a;b;k;f;e;g;c;l;d
Input:  1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Output: 6;3;8;2;4;7;5;1
```